# MaterializeCss ScrollFire: how to add 'this selector' in fallback

Tags: jquery, materialize

On my page some classes `.wow`, and I want trigger current element, not all.
My code, that doesn't work:

```
var options = [
    {selector: '.wow', offset: 200, callback: '$(this).addClass("animated")' },
];
Materialize.scrollFire(options);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use an ID rather than a class if you just want to effect one item.

```
var options = [
    {selector: '#myelement1', offset: 200, callback: '$(this).addClass("animated")' },
];
Materialize.scrollFire(options);
```

And then for the HTML,

```
<span class="wow" id="myelement1">Hello, World!</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

let me see if I understand you correctly, .wow classes are mainly used by a plugin named wow.js, which does the sames thing as Materializedcss scrollfire plugin does. You should either use wow.js or materializedcss scrollfire plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Just came across this and this answer will be no use to the OP now, but just leaving this post in a better place...

There are three problems:

1. The callback is a string, remove the single quotes.
2. The callback is not a function. Wrap the JQuery selector and method with a function.
3. The JQuery selector references `this` which probably references the `options` array (haven't checked). It needs to reference `.wow`
4. Then as Eddie Hart mentioned use a unique selector such as an id of an element.

---

```
var options = [
  {
    selector: '.wow', 
    offset: 200, 
    callback: function() {               // Callback needs to be a function.
      $('.wow').addClass("animated");    // Reference `.wow` not `this`.
    }
  }
];
Materialize.scrollFire(options);
```